# sacar diferente datos x partes con simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php

tengo dificultades para poder mostrar diferentes datos extraidos de una web, por el momento este es el unico codigo que me funciona:

```
<?php
require'includes/simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('https://materialesandersen.com.ar/corralon/obra-gruesa/aridos/');
foreach ($html->find( 'ul.products img' ) as $element)
   echo "
  <div class='col-3 border'>
    <div class=row>
      <div class='col-6'>
        <img src=".$element->src ." class=img-fluid>
      </div>
      <div class=col-6>
        <p>hola</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ";
  ?>
```

con este codigo puedo mostrar las imagenes de la pagina, pero tambien necesito mostrar la descripcion, pero nbo logro hacerlo, si a esta linea:

```
foreach ($html->find( 'ul.products img' ) as $element)
```

le saco la el tag img ya ni me muestra la imagen,los datos que necesito extraer estan dentro de un li dentro de como veran el ul.products, alguna ayuda x favor

haciendo var_dump($element); tira demasiada data que no termina de cargar la pagina

cambiando el foreach por esto:

```
foreach ($html->find( 'ul.products li' ) as $element)
```

tengo que cambiar esta linea:

```
<img src=".$element->src ." class=img-fluid>
```

por esta:

```
<p>".$element ." </p>
```

es la unica manera de que me devuelva algo y me devuelve todo el conjunto de datos que necesito, pero lo que busco es manejar esos datos independientemente uno de otros

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($element);` y agrégalo a la pregunta pulsando en [edit]  para ver qué hay en el contenido exactamente. Y, sería interesante ver qué arroja esto: `foreach ($html->find( 'ul.products li' ) as $element)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder resolver tu problema es mejor que todos los resultados los pases a un arreglo, me di a la tarea de meterme al sitio y ver su estructura, con esto logre sacar los siguientes datos:

- URL de imagen
- Descripción
- Precio (solo si tienen)

Así quedo el codigo:

```
$html = file_get_html('https://materialesandersen.com.ar/corralon/obra-gruesa/aridos/');
$arreglo = $ainter = array();
$a = -1;
if($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes)) {
    foreach ($html->find('ul.products img, .desc h4, .desc .price') as $e) {
        if (!$e->src && $e->plaintext == ''):
            break;
        elseif (!$e->src):
            $ainter[] = $e->plaintext;
        else:
            $ainter[] = $e->src;
        endif;
    }
    foreach ($ainter as $as){
        if (strpos($as, 'https') !== false) {
            $arreglo[++$a]['img'] = $as;
        }elseif (strpos($as, '.') !== false) {
            $arreglo[$a]['precio'] = $as;
        }else{
            $arreglo[$a]['desc'] = $as;
        }
    }
}
```

Y al imprimir el `$arreglo` arroja:

```
Dump => array(15) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    ["img"] => string(85) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/canto-rodado-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(18) "Canto rodado x m³"
  }
  [1] => array(3) {
    ["img"] => string(87) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/arena-en-bolsa-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(14) "Arena en Bolsa"
    ["precio"] => string(28) "$ 114.00  $ 108.30  "
  }
  [2] => array(3) {
    ["img"] => string(96) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Cascote-Picado-en-Bolsa-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(23) "Cascote Picado en Bolsa"
    ["precio"] => string(28) "$ 116.00  $ 110.20  "
  }
  [3] => array(3) {
    ["img"] => string(88) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Piedra-en-Bolsa-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(15) "Piedra en Bolsa"
    ["precio"] => string(28) "$ 162.00  $ 153.90  "
  }
  [4] => array(3) {
    ["img"] => string(83) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Tosca-x-m3-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(11) "Tosca x m³"
    ["precio"] => string(28) "$ 850.00  $ 807.50  "
  }
  [5] => array(3) {
    ["img"] => string(97) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Cascote-picado-en-bolson-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(20) "Cascote picado x m³"
    ["precio"] => string(30) "$ 1,000.00  $ 902.50  "
  }
  [6] => array(3) {
    ["img"] => string(92) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/venta-de-arena-x-m3-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(10) "Arena x m3"
    ["precio"] => string(32) "$ 1,410.00  $ 1,339.50  "
  }
  [7] => array(3) {
    ["img"] => string(99) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/cascote-picado-en-bolson-1-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(24) "Cascote Picado en Bolson"
    ["precio"] => string(32) "$ 1,412.00  $ 1,341.40  "
  }
  [8] => array(3) {
    ["img"] => string(88) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/arena-en-bolson-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(16) "Arena en Bolsón"
    ["precio"] => string(32) "$ 1,822.00  $ 1,730.90  "
  }
  [9] => array(3) {
    ["img"] => string(89) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Piedra-6-20-x-m3-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(17) "Piedra 6/20 x m³"
    ["precio"] => string(32) "$ 2,630.00  $ 2,498.50  "
  }
  [10] => array(3) {
    ["img"] => string(90) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/piedra-binder-3-6-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(23) "Piedra Binder 3/6 x m³"
    ["precio"] => string(32) "$ 2,800.00  $ 2,660.00  "
  }
  [11] => array(3) {
    ["img"] => string(96) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/piedra-6-20-en-bolson-1-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(22) "Piedra 6/20 en Bolsón"
    ["precio"] => string(32) "$ 3,042.00  $ 2,889.90  "
  }
  [12] => array(3) {
    ["img"] => string(96) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/piedra-6-20-en-bolson-1-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(28) "Piedra Binder 3/6 en Bolsón"
    ["precio"] => string(32) "$ 3,212.00  $ 3,051.40  "
  }
  [13] => array(3) {
    ["img"] => string(86) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/piedra-blanca-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(19) "Piedra blanca x m³"
    ["precio"] => string(32) "$ 3,358.00  $ 3,190.10  "
  }
  [14] => array(3) {
    ["img"] => string(93) "https://materialesandersen.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/bolson-piedra-blanca-300x420.jpg"
    ["desc"] => string(24) "Piedra blanca en bolsón"
    ["precio"] => string(32) "$ 3,770.00  $ 3,581.50  "
  }
}
```

Para poder ahora listar los productos scrapeados:

```
<?php foreach ($arreglo as $a): ?>
<div class='col-3 border'>
    <div class=row>
        <div class='col-6'>
            <img src="<?= $arreglo['img'] ?>" class=img-fluid>
        </div>
        <div class=col-6>
            <p><?= $arreglo['desc']?> <?php if(isset($arreglo['precio'])): ?> Precio: <?php echo $arreglo['precio']; endif;?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```